# How do I add a top side to a model i cut in half?

Tags: modeling

[image: This is the thing I want to put the top on]

I making a somewhat broken staircase railing and I was wondering how I would put a top side on this.

Comment: Select outer edge and try Fill grid or Loop Tool addon. Or select outer edge, extrude and scale to zero. Or use just Solidify modifier with value that fills the hole.

Comment: Thank you very much :D